# Calling Dispatch function from a blank javascript file

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So i'm writing a React-Redux web app, and i call dispatch from my react components like this :

```
this.props.dispatch(someAction());
```

Now i need to call dispatch from a javascript function that is not a React Component, so how do i import the dispatch function and use it in this case ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The `dispatch` function is a member of your redux [store](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#dispatch). If you created and exported your store in a module, it would be as easy as importing the store in your module and calling the `dispatch` function.

Example:

```
// store.js
import { createStore } from 'redux'

export default createStore(reducers)


// somefile.js
import store from './store'

store.dispatch(someAction)
```

Comment: does this still enable the subscription in react components? just tried this but mapStateToProps is not called when dispatch is invoked from store outside the component

Comment: The subscription works the same, `connect` from `react-redux` connects to the store and `mapStateToProps` is called every time the store updates. Is it possible that the action is dispatched before the react component is first rendered, e.g. during the initial bootstrapping of the app?

Comment: yeah, it was because of misfiring the action before the component is rendered, my bad.

Comment: Please note that the action must also be imported :) plus1

Comment: Please note that the action must also be imported :) plus1

Comment: Is there a reason to use one over the other? I mean... it looks simpler to import *store* and use *store.dispatch* even inside a component;

Answer (score 2):

The [dispatch method](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#dispatchaction) is one of the [store](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#dispatchaction)'s methods. react-redux makes `dispatch` available to components as props via the `provider`, and `mapDispatchToProps`.

You can dispatch directly from the [store](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html):

```
store.dispatch(action)
```