# React Redux - using dispatch() outside component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, dispatch

Is it possible to dispatch action outside React component?

```
import dispatch from 'react';
...
dispatch(actionCreator())
```

or:

```
bindActionCreators(actionCreator, dispatch)();
```

has no effect.

(FYI, I am trying to invoke action from `axios` interceptor - I just have found `redux-axios-middleware`, but I would like not to integrate it yet).

Comment: If you want to dispatch the action outside of react/redux you should subscribe to store and then dispatch the action. More info: http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#subscribe, but it is unlikely you would need to do it, what are trying to achieve ?

Comment: `dispatch` is not a function from the react module, it is a function on your redux store. You can call it wherever you'd like in your code, but you'll need a reference to your store to call `dispatch`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45043219/calling-dispatch-function-from-a-blank-javascript-file